# How to transfer excel formula to octave?

Tags: matlab, octave, freemat

As you can see the image (excel file) I would like to use that formula in Octave to get the desired result. I also uploaded the octave codes picture and the workspace picture too. In workspace my result/values for storage variable should be the same values like that in excel (storage column). I have a doubt that in the code the last part using (if statement with i-1 is seems to be the error).

Can someone help me to figure it out? Let me know if any further clarifications required. Also I am posting my code below too:

```
BM_max = 1236;
virtual_feed_max = 64;
operation = dlmread ('2020Operation.csv');
BM = ones (size (operation, 1), 1);
for i=1:size(operation,1)
  if operation(i,1)==1
    BM(i,1)=BM_max;
  else
    BM(i,1)=0;
  end
end
virtual_feed = ones(size(operation,1),1);
virtual_feed(:,1) = 64;
storage = ones(size(BM,1),1);
c = ones(size(BM,1),1);
for i=1:size(BM,1)
  c=(BM(:,1)-virtual_feed(:,1));
end
for i=1:size(BM,1)
  if ((i=1)&& c)<0
    storage(:,1)=0;
  elseif ((i=1)&& c)>0 
    storage(:,1)=c;
  else
  # Issue is below (Taking the value from subsequent row is the problem) 
    if (c+(storage(i-1,1)))<0  
      storage(:,1)=0;
    elseif (c+(storage(i-1,1)))>0  
      storage(:,1)=(c+(storage(i-1,1)));
    end    
  end
end
```

[Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrDI3.png) [Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQeSt.png)

Comment: All I see is one broken link to one image. Please include your code as text, properly formatted, not as an image.

Comment: I have included the code too. Looking for your suggestions

Comment: First, `((i=1)&& c)<0` seems wrong, perhaps you meant `((i==1)&& c<0)`? It would also be better if you formatted your code as a [code block](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: ((i=1)&& c)<0 is what I meant. Since I am new to stackoverflow not able to use code block. You can see the two images the excel file picture can explain to u in a better way. Looking for your comments

Comment: `((i=1)&&c)<0` sets the variable `i` to the value `1`, then performs the logical AND of `i` and `c`, which can only be true or false and is never less than zero. **All** users can use code blocks as described in the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Now I think you can get my point as I edited the code as per code block suggestions.

Comment: How is adding `<` and `>` around each line equivalent to "Indent four spaces..." or "select a block of code and press ctrl K"? Please read the section marked "**Code Blocks**" at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting. Then, in your workspace, set `i` and `c` to whatever values you like and type the command `((i=1)&& c)<0`. Verify that the result is what you expect it to be.

Comment: with Andy's help the code was edited. Let me know ur suggestions

Comment: Please rethink your `if ((i=1)&& c)<0` and `elseif ((i=1)&& c)>0`. As beaker already said it's a big difference between `i=1` and `i==1`. The first "stores" a 1 into i and returns always true, the second checks if i is equal to 1 and returns true in this case.

Comment: Even if I use if ((i==1)&& c)<0 and elseif ((i==1)&& c)>0. I am not able to get the desired result. I have no idea where the error is? Totally confused

Comment: I suggest you step through your code line by line and make sure that the result of each line is what you expect it to be. When you find an discrepancy, correct the error and continue. Trying to fix everything at once will only leave you overwhelmed and unable to make progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is the following (as seen from your Excel screenshot)

```
BM_max = 1236;
virtual_feed_max = 64;
operation = [0; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 1; 0; 0; 0; 0; 0];

BM = BM_max * operation;
virtual_feed = repmat (virtual_feed_max, size (operation));

storage = zeros (size (operation));
for i=2:numel (storage)
  storage (i) = max (BM(i) - virtual_feed(i) + storage(i-1), 0);
endfor

storage
```

which outputs:

```
storage =

      0
   1172
   2344
   3516
   4688
   5860
   7032
   8204
   8140
   8076
   8012
   7948
   7884
```

I leave the part of vectorization to make it faster for you. (hint: have a look at `cumsum`)

Answer (score 0):

From this point on

```
for i=1:size(BM,1)
  if ((i=1)&& c)<0
    storage(:,1)=0;
  elseif ((i=1)&& c)>0 
    storage(:,1)=c;
  else
  # Issue is below (Taking the value from subsequent row is the problem) 
    if (c+(storage(i-1,1)))<0  
      storage(:,1)=0;
    elseif (c+(storage(i-1,1)))>0  
      storage(:,1)=(c+(storage(i-1,1)));
    end    
  end
end
```

you are not changing a single value in `storage` but all the row/column, so each iteration, all the row/column is being changed instead of a single "cell".
You should use something like this:

```
storage(i,1) = 0;
```

BTW, a lot of those 'for' loops can be changed to vector operations. Example:

```
for i=1:size(BM,1)
  c=(BM(:,1)-virtual_feed(:,1));
end
```

Can be changed for:

```
c = BM - virtual_feed;
```